# Boot from USB option not available in Acer Aspire ES1-132 boot menu

Tags: acer-aspire

I have purchased Acer Aspire ES1-132. There is no legacy or UEFI option boot menu, only secure boot enable|disable option is available.  I have given first priority to boot from USB but directly linpus linux is loading, please help

Answer (score 0):

1. download https://rufus.akeo.ie/downloads/rufus-2.16.exe and Install Rufus
2. Select GPT Partition Scheme For UEFI
3. Create a bootable disk using iso image

Answer (score 0):

If you enabled the `F12 Bootmenu` from the bios (its under the `Main` tab) you should be able to boot into the bootmenu by holding <kbd>F12</kbd> during startup. it will list all current bootable bootdevices the system could find.

If your usb bootdevice isnt listed, either select `UEFI` under `bootmode` (tab `boot`) or check if the filesystem is correct and the EFI files are correctly installed. I asume Secureboot to be disabled.

follow Hendra Syahrial answer for example to make a EFI bootable usbdrive.(Rufus, unetbootin)